# Select value from one column with multiple values in other columns

Tags: sql

I have the following data:

column1--        column2

cl1  --------    pl1
cl2  --------    pl1
cl3  --------      pl2

pl1 has is related to two different values in column1 (cl1,cl2) .what I need is a query that returns pl1 and any other values in column2 that corresponds to more than one value in column1.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this may work; but it really depends on context and use.

```
SELECT count(distinct column1), column2
FROM tableName
GROUP BY column2
HAVING count(distinct column1) > 1
```

Distinct is only necessary if column1 can have the same value multiple times in compared to column2... 
For example...

```
cl1 pl1
cl1 pl1  <-- if data like this  and before doesn't exist then you don't need the distinct
cl2 pl1
cl3 pl2
cl4 pl2
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, this works

If we have a table

```
Name      Make
Accord    Honda
Camry     Toyota
Corolla   Toyota
Crosstrek Subaru
```

Use this

```
SELECT Make FROM CARS GROUP BY Make HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: if 'Accord', Honda' existed a second time would the results be accurate?

Comment: I am assuming that the user does not care about duplicate data, and just wants any value on cloumn 2 that repeats